# Prove that $\sin^2x \cos^2x = \frac{1}{8}(1-\cos(4x))$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm struggling to show that $\sin^2x\cos^2x = \frac{1}{8}(1-\cos(4x))$.

Knowing that

1. $\sin^2x = \frac{1}{2}(1-\cos(2x))$
2. $\cos^2x = \frac{1}{2}(1+\cos(2x))$

It follows that:
$\sin^2x \cos^2x = \frac{1}{2}(1-\cos(2x))\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos(2x))$

Combining like terms:
$\sin^2x \cos^2x = \frac{1}{4} (1+\cos^2(2x))$

Eq2 can be used again to reduce the power, here

$\sin^2x \cos^2x = \frac{1}{4} (1 + \frac{1}{2}(1 + \cos(4x)))$

And combining like terms

$\sin^2x \cos^2x = \frac{1}{4} (1 + (\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{2}\cos(4x))$

$\sin^2x \cos^2x = \frac{1}{4} +  \frac{1}{8}+ \frac{1}{8}\cos(4x)$

$\sin^2x \cos^2x = \frac{1}{8} ( 3 + \cos(4x)) $

But I seem to get nowhere...

Comment: Combining like terms, $(1-\cos 2x)(1+\cos 2x)$ should be $1-\cos^2 2x$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that $\sin^2 \theta \cdot \cos^2\theta = (1/8)[1 - \cos(4 \theta)]$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1761823/show-that-sin2-theta-cdot-cos2-theta-1-81-cos4-theta) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csin%5E2x%5Ccos%5E2x%3D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B8%7D(1-%5Ccos(4x))%24&p=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
{1\over8}(1-\cos4x)&={1\over8}(1-(2\cos^22x-1))\\
&={1\over4}(1-\cos^22x)\\
&={1\over4}\sin^22x\\
&={1\over4}(2\sin x\cos x)^2\\
&=\sin^2x\cos^2x
\end{align}$$

Comment: please refrain from answering dupe questions

Comment: Ok! Can you just explain why? Someone already told him this is a dupe, so instead of new people that are going to search for the answer on this question and then will go to the other question(with the answer) I just added the answer here, so that they won't need to wonder the site to find the answer to the question! Thansk!

Comment: @There is a simpler way,Just recommend Approach0 search engine,This will be easier

Comment: But he won't(probably) delete he question, so people will still be able to see this question, so instead of wondering and seeking for the answer in the comment section, they can just see it here. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, People who will search for similar question would also see similar question that was posted earlier, So it makes no sense to answer it again to make it more easy to access, Because, People searching for it will anyways see the original question, Also, he purpose of posing a question as duplicates is to Collect all answers at one place, For this specific case, There are different type of answers including similar to your answer in the original question Posted earlier

Comment: So you are saying that if I have had an answer that wasn't on the other questions, then it'd be OK?

Comment: Then I would Have recommended you to delete This answer and Answer it Over the Earlier post, Why? Again, The objective of Duplicate questions is to accumulate all different answers to Same question at one place, and avoid mess

Comment: @Chessplayer You're not wrong giving the answer, but if there was an answer to the original question, it's easier to direct them to the other answer than adding several duplicate answers.  It's also better to give hints depending on how far the OP got.  If they're thisclose to the answer, a hint is all they need to complete their work.  If not, it's seen as doing their work for them.

Answer (score 1):

Hints (going from $\sin^2 x \cos^2 x = \frac {1}{8} (1-\cos 4x)$):

1. $(\sin x \cos x) = \frac {1}{2} \sin 2x$
2. After squaring both sides, $\sin^2 2x = 1-\cos^2 2x$
3. $\cos 4x = 2 \cos^2 2x - 1$ hence $\cos^2 2x = \dfrac {\cos 4x + 1}{2}$